# Heapsize error on Queueable class

Tags: httprequest, queueable-apex, asyncapexjob

I have a queueable class and I am doing a REST Callout. I am sending 2 files that are less than 12MB. When I run the code I am getting a Heap size error. Salesforce document says if you use Asyncrous code then the maximum heap size will be 12MB. Any idea how i can fix this issue.

> ```
> req.setTimeout(120000); 
> req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json'); 
> req.setBody(Json.serialize(fileMap));
> ```

```
22:42:37.0 (760194943)|METHOD_ENTRY|[95]||System.JSON.serialize(Object)
22:42:37.0 (918391327)|METHOD_EXIT|[95]||System.JSON.serialize(Object)
22:42:37.0 (918515404)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: JSON string exceeds heap size limit
```

Answer (score 0):

As it looks like `fileMap` may be containing `String` base64 version of the file.

Thus, File Size may not be 12MB but the base64 version form of it can be more that 12MB of characters. **Also the heap size is for the full transaction.**

Its better to keep a check of heap size (`LIMIT class`) and to make separate callout for another file. If it goes beyond your heap limit.

Comment: Hi @Nagendra, I tried the Limit class. I am not able to see the value because I am getting the error on Json.serialize(fileMap). Before JSON string I have a Limit class and the value is 2567. I have a 10MB file attached.

Comment: Base64 version of a file will always be greater than binary file size. So you may have to limit it to max 5-6 MB of file size.